# Line Graph in Java(not a jfreechart)

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I have 2 sets of array x and y read from a .txt file and I need to put it in a line graph. 
so far this is my code:

```
    import java.awt.BasicStroke;
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.FontMetrics;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.Point;
    import java.awt.RenderingHints;
    import java.awt.Stroke;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Random;
    import java.awt.Font;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

    public class DrawGraph extends JPanel  {

private int width = 800;
private int heigth = 400;
private int padding = 25;
private int labelPadding = 25;
private Color lineColor = new Color(44, 102, 230, 180);
private Color pointColor = new Color(100, 100, 100, 180);
private Color gridColor = new Color(200, 200, 200, 200);
private static final Stroke GRAPH_STROKE = new BasicStroke(2f);
private int pointWidth = 4;
private int numberYDivisions = 10;
private List<Double> scores;
private int xp;
private int yp; 

public DrawGraph(List<Double> scores){
    this.scores=scores;
}
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

    double xScale = ((double) getWidth() - (2 * padding) - labelPadding) / (scores.size() - 1);
    double yScale = ((double) getHeight() - 2 * padding - labelPadding) / (getMaxScore() - getMinScore());

    List<Point> graphPoints = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < scores.size(); i++) {
        int x1 = (int) (i * xScale + padding + labelPadding);
        int y1 = (int) ((getMaxScore() - scores.get(i)) * yScale + padding);
        graphPoints.add(new Point(x1, y1));
    }

    // draw white background
    g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g2.fillRect(padding + labelPadding, padding, getWidth() - (2 * padding) - labelPadding,
            getHeight() - 2 * padding - labelPadding);
    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    // create hatch marks and grid lines for y axis.
    for (int i = 0; i < numberYDivisions + 1; i++) {
        int x0 = padding + labelPadding;
        int x1 = pointWidth + padding + labelPadding;
        int y0 = getHeight()
                - ((i * (getHeight() - padding * 2 - labelPadding)) / numberYDivisions + padding + labelPadding);
        int y1 = y0;
        if (scores.size() > 0) {
            g2.setColor(gridColor);
            g2.drawLine(padding + labelPadding + 1 + pointWidth, y0, getWidth() - padding, y1);
            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            String yLabel = ((int) ((getMinScore()
                    + (getMaxScore() - getMinScore()) * ((i * 1.0) / numberYDivisions)) * 100)) / 100.0 + "";
            FontMetrics metrics = g2.getFontMetrics();
            int labelWidth = metrics.stringWidth(yLabel);
            g2.drawString(yLabel, x0 - labelWidth - 5, y0 + (metrics.getHeight() / 2) - 3);
        }
        g2.drawLine(x0, y0, x1, y1);
    }

    // and for x axis
    for (int i = 0; i < scores.size(); i++) {
        if (scores.size() > 1) {
            int x0 = i * (getWidth() - padding * 2 - labelPadding) / (scores.size() - 1) + padding + labelPadding;
            int x1 = x0;
            int y0 = getHeight() - padding - labelPadding;
            int y1 = y0 - pointWidth;
            if ((i % ((int) ((scores.size() / 20.0)) + 1)) == 0) {
                g2.setColor(gridColor);
                g2.drawLine(x0, getHeight() - padding - labelPadding - 1 - pointWidth, x1, padding);
                g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                String xLabel = i + "";
                FontMetrics metrics = g2.getFontMetrics();
                int labelWidth = metrics.stringWidth(xLabel);
                g2.drawString(xLabel, x0 - labelWidth / 2, y0 + metrics.getHeight() + 3);
            }
            g2.drawLine(x0, y0, x1, y1);
        }
    }

    // create x and y axes
    g2.drawLine(padding + labelPadding, getHeight() - padding - labelPadding, padding + labelPadding, padding);
    g2.drawLine(padding + labelPadding, getHeight() - padding - labelPadding, getWidth() - padding,
            getHeight() - padding - labelPadding);

    Stroke oldStroke = g2.getStroke();
    g2.setColor(lineColor);
    g2.setStroke(GRAPH_STROKE);
    for (int i = 0; i < graphPoints.size() - 1; i++) {
        int x1 = graphPoints.get(i).x;
        int y1 = graphPoints.get(i).y;
        int x2 = graphPoints.get(i + 1).x;
        int y2 = graphPoints.get(i + 1).y;
        g2.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }

    g2.setStroke(oldStroke);
    g2.setColor(pointColor);
    for (int i = 0; i < graphPoints.size(); i++) {
        int x = graphPoints.get(i).x - pointWidth / 2;
        int y = graphPoints.get(i).y - pointWidth / 2;
        int ovalW = pointWidth;
        int ovalH = pointWidth;
        g2.fillOval(x, y, ovalW, ovalH);
    }
}

// @Override
// public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
// return new Dimension(width, heigth);
// }
private double getMinScore() {
    double minScore = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    for (Double score : scores) {
        minScore = Math.min(minScore, score);
    }
    return minScore;
}

private double getMaxScore() {
    double maxScore = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    for (Double score : scores) {
        maxScore = Math.max(maxScore, xp);
    }
    return maxScore;
}

public void setScores(List<Double> scores) {
    this.scores = scores;
    invalidate();
    this.repaint();
}

public List<Double> getScores() {
    return scores;
}

private static void createAndShowGui() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    List<Double> scores = new ArrayList<>();
    BufferedReader br  = new BufferedReader(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Johanna\\Desktop\\values.txt")));
        String line = "";
        while((line = br.readLine())!=null){
             String[] t = line.split(",");
             double x = Double.parseDouble(t[0].trim());
             double y = Double.parseDouble(t[1].trim());

    }
    MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel(scores);
    mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("DrawGraph");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                createAndShowGui();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DrawGraph.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    });
}

//Main changes underneath

static class MainPanel extends JPanel {

    public MainPanel(List<Double> scores) {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JLabel title = new JLabel("");
        title.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 25));
        title.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

        JPanel DrawGraph = new DrawGraph(scores);

        VerticalPanel vertPanel = new VerticalPanel();

        HorizontalPanel horiPanel = new HorizontalPanel();

        add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(horiPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(vertPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(DrawGraph, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }

    class VerticalPanel extends JPanel {

        public VerticalPanel() {
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(25, 0));
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D gg = (Graphics2D) g;
            gg.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

            Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 15);

            String string = "Transmittance";

            FontMetrics metrics = g.getFontMetrics(font);
            int width = metrics.stringWidth(string);
            int height = metrics.getHeight();

            gg.setFont(font);

            drawRotate(gg, getWidth(), (getHeight() + width) / 2, 270, string);
        }

        public void drawRotate(Graphics2D gg, double x, double y, int angle, String text) {
            gg.translate((float) x, (float) y);
            gg.rotate(Math.toRadians(angle));
            gg.drawString(text, 0, 0);
            gg.rotate(-Math.toRadians(angle));
            gg.translate(-(float) x, -(float) y);
        }

    }

    class HorizontalPanel extends JPanel {

        public HorizontalPanel() {
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 25));
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D gg = (Graphics2D) g;
            gg.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

            Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 15);

            String string = "Wavenumber (cm)";

            FontMetrics metrics = g.getFontMetrics(font);
            int width = metrics.stringWidth(string);
            int height = metrics.getHeight();

            gg.setFont(font);

            gg.drawString(string, (getWidth() - width) / 2, 11);
        }


    }

  }

 }
```

This is what i tried. It doesn't work :( Why it doesn't work? 
..............................................................

Comment: What is your exact issue?

Comment: I want to convert it into a line graph. I saw some codes exactly what i want. I just don't know how to insert my codes because whenever I try to put my codes it doesnt run.

Comment: You should show some effort, maybe you could post one of your "try" and tell us exactly what's not working with it. Feel also free to read this [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section

Comment: As an hint, you **never** use your x, y (in `Double.parseDouble(t[0].trim());`)